# json seem enable but cannot run json_encode

Tags: php, pear, json

My PHP version is 5.1.6
I have install Json by follow the instructions:

```
# yum install php-devel
# yum install php-pear
# yum install gcc
# pear install json
# cd /etc/php.d
# echo "extension=json.so" > json.ini
# service httpd restart
```

Now, I check that Json enabled, but I cannot run json_encode:

Check 1:

```
[root@69-64-69-43 ~]# php -i | grep json
```

Result 1:

```
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
json
json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1
```

Check 2:

```
[root@69-64-69-43 ~]# php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("json_encode"));'
```

Result 2:

```
bool(true)
```

But when run:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() in /var/www/vhosts/ykite.com/httpdocs/fre/json.php on line 8
```

Here is run link:

Check Json: http://69.64.69.43/fre/json.php

php_info(): http://69.64.69.43/fre/info.php

I was really looking and read many documents but I can not find the cause of this case.

I sincerely appreciate your help.

Cuong

Comment: Checked phpinfo() to see if your extension is enabled?

Comment: I check my phpinfo(): http://69.64.69.43/fre/info.php, it loaded json.ini, but don't see any other reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `var_dump( function_exists( 'json_encode' ) )` returns true, while your HTTP request says the function doesn't exist; there's only one explanation I can think of: CLI and HTTP requests use a different php.ini. In your `phpinfo( )` document, it says that it's loading json.ini, but I don't see any other reference to JSON in there.

Check your logs to see whether or not json.so is actually loaded upon a HTTP request. My bet is that it isn't.

Comment: I found json.so in: /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so, Is there any way to check where php.ini used by CLI?

Comment: I found in log file: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Check the user and group of json.so, and check whether or not the PHP user can execute that.

Comment: [root@69-64-69-43 ~]# ls -l /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 92886 May  1 23:58 /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so
[root@69-64-69-43 ~]# ls -l /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 53008 Feb 22 17:30 /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so

Comment: I found the answer for this case. I will read more about SELinux.

These guidelines have helped me to enable json_encode for http request:
https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=27117

Just disable SELinux or change it with command:

    chcon system_u:object_r:textrel_shlib_t /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so

Sloved & Thanks so much.

Comment: @CuongPham Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

From [Let's Install JSON for PHP 5](http://slaptijack.com/system-administration/lets-install-json-for-php-5/)

> **Install json** - This was actually trickier than expected. I assumed I would be able to install this via `pear`. Apparently, a [PEAR Services_JSON package](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198) was developed, but it has never been accepted into the official repository. The trick instead is to use the [PECL json package](http://pecl.php.net/package/json). This was as easy as running `pecl install json` and watching the compiler do its thing. When it's done you should have a `json.so` file in your PHP modules directory. (Mine is `/usr/lib/php/modules/`.)

Comment: I also think it is easy to install like that, I had successfully installed on another server. My json.so in: /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so

Comment: From your phpinfo page: **Configuration File (php.ini) Path:** `/etc/php.ini` Try adding `extension= /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so` in this .ini file to test it

Comment: Seem not work. I get this error: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules//usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules//usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Okay I am sorry, it seems that the path is added automatically. Then just write `extension=json.so`

Comment: Not like we think: PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this is an old topic, but maybe someone will stumble across this like I did in August 2015.  I fixed this by changing the extensions folder path in php.ini.  It was somehow set to "./" and not /usr/lib64/php/modules/