# getting error while converting xml to json

Tags: php, xml, json, parsing

I am getting **undefined function** error when i am using `json_encode()` function. I need to convert the xml data to json data.
The code i am using is :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($retValue);
echo json_encode($xml);
```

I also tried this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($retValue);
$array = objectsIntoArray($xml);
$array = json_encode($array);
print_r($array);
die;

function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $arrSkipIndices = array())
{

    $arrData = array();
    if (is_object($arrObjData)) {
        $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);
    }
    if (is_array($arrObjData)) {
        foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {
            if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
                $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $arrSkipIndices);
            }
            if (in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices)) {
                continue;
            }
            $arrData[$index] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arrData;
}
```

But in this `objectsIntoArray()` and `json_encode()` both are throwing function undefined errors.
`$retValue` contains the xml data. I am not able to figure out why i am getting this error.
Am i missing something. I am totally new to php and not much aware of it.
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Post the _complete_ error message. Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: the complete error i am getting is:"Call to undefined function objectsIntoArray()" . Same error message for json_encode()

Comment: @sneha You won't get that error if the code is exactly like the code above. So you're doing something different that posted.

Comment: @Arnold....I just posted the same code i am using.

Comment: Do i need to include any other libraries for this? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PHP doesn't have the JSON extension enabled. Starting from PHP 5.2.0 the JSON extension is bundled and enabled by default. However you can still build PHP with JSON.

You should check if this is the case by creating a script called `phpinfo.php`, with the code:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

Open the script in your browser. And check if you can find a section named **json**. Also check your PHP version.

```
json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1
```

If you're using PHP 5.1.x, [install the extension using pecl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php). Otherwise, please tell which OS (and distro) you're using and how you've installed PHP.

If you did not install PHP yourself, contact your sysadmin / hosting provider.

Alternatively you can use this [pure PHP json library](https://gist.github.com/itspriddle/845016).

Comment: @Arnold....and y is it that m getting the same error for objectsIntoArray() function call?

Comment: ok can i use something other than this? i need to show the xml data in a datatable. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @sneha Added a lib to the answer. Did you check phpinfo?

Comment: @Arnold...Yes  i checked the phpinfo. version is 5.2.6

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have older version of php  4.3.1. or Your `simplexml_load_string` is disable.
Check with 
echo phpinfo();

Comment: please post the full error message. Also check the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409756/json-seem-enable-but-cannot-run-json-encode