# How to get only one argument value sent as JSON

Tags: php, json

my link to my web page is like this

> `http://mysite.php?json={"some_key":"some_val"}`

```
$json=$_GET ['json'];  
$obj = json_decode($json);
#this line print the whole input 
echo $json."</br>";

#but this does not print anythig 
echo $obj->{'some_key'}."</br>";
```

I am new to php and I get stuck in the reading input... :(

**edit

My point is to take the some_val into variable so I can make decisions according the value...

For me is the easiest way to put it in the url, but if I have to I will implement POST method.

The code I need should look like this

> $variable=(read the value for the key "some_key")

Comment: Why are you sending json in url???

Comment: You should send JSON in $_POST

Comment: I need some input to my php before it stars his work...,

Comment: You can create in javaScript Object -> JSON.stringify -> POST -> Your script -> json_decode -> done.

Comment: var_dump($_GET) will save your life

Comment: @carter - var_dump($_GET);  :)

Comment: @JanCzarny IDE's save my life

Comment: second question @Lukap - what is your target? What you want? (more description -> for example -> i want eat apple ex.)

Comment: @carter - manual is my second bible

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php `$json=$_GET ['json'];` to `$json=urldecode($_GET['json']);` - it's may work?

Comment: try print_r($obj); to see what's the return of json_decode

Comment: This is supposed to work. Maybe you don't have json enabled. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409756/json-seem-enable-but-cannot-run-json-encode

Comment: print_r($obj); is empty but echo $json; print something like this {\'some_key\':\"some_val\"}

Comment: echo $obj->some_key
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `echo $json` will print content of `$_GET['json']`, because its the same. And thats the same, as you have in your url - `{"some_key":"some_val"}`, and its escaped... Are you really sure you want to code in PHP? ;-)

Comment: @lukap `$json=html_entity_decode(urldecode($_GET['json']));` try_it

Comment: @JanCzarny Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in ...

Comment: @lukap - fixed -  copy again

Comment: @JanCzarny it prints {"some_key":"some_val"} the problem is I need just the "some_val" that is the part I can not do it :)

Comment: @lukap change  `echo $obj->{'some_key'}."</br>";` to `echo $obj->some_key."</br>";`

Comment: @JanCzarny empty again :( ... maybe I must do in with POST not with GET

Comment: @lukap -> I will back for a 1hour. (And I will make solve)

Comment: @JanCzarny Thanks for the effort, just to let you know that I post the php code to 000webhost.com

Comment: @lukap - Updated! (it's should work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**rollup**

INPUT

```
 http://urlblabla/test.php?json={"some_key":"some_val"}
```

Code after some patches:

decode from url form to normal, and delete html entity

CODE:

```
<?php

if(IsSet($_GET['json']))
{
    $json = html_entity_decode( urldecode( $_GET['json'] ) ); 
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    #this line print the whole input 
    echo $json."</br>";

    #but this does not print anythig 
    echo "Value of some_key : '{$obj->some_key}'</br>";

    #into variable (assign some_key value to variable $var)
    $var = $obj->some_key;

    echo "Value of var : '{$var}' <br />";

}
?>
```

Comment: I work on 000webhost.com , so maybe the problem is they do not support this kind of json passing...

Comment: read my question!, I post code that I wrote so far, but if you have some idea that should be done different that post code, do not look my code..., I only need code that will read the "some_key" in a variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for basic url query params:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?somekey=someval
```

In php:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['somekey'] ) && $_GET['somekey'] == 'someval') {
   $variable = $_GET['somekey']; // example of assigning GET param to variable
   echo "do something!";
}
```

If you are intent on passing json in as a url param:

```
$json = json_decode($_GET['json']);
echo $json->some_key;
```

Comment: this is not what I looking for , I have problems with the json part not with reading simple parameters...