# ERROR The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

I'm on Ubuntu LTS 14.04, and since one day. I get the following error when going to phpMyAdmin on my localhost.

> The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

I already tried installing it from scratch but it won't work. When I check `php5 -m` the JSON extension is installed. Does anyone know what would solve this problem?

Comment: did you checked in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409756/json-seem-enable-but-cannot-run-json-encode)

Comment: I suspect you checked your console PHP but not your web server PHP - they often run from separate ini files. Don't forget to restart Apache once you have reconfigured.

Comment: json support  enabled
json version  1.3.2
JSON-C version (bundled)  0.11 

This is what i got at the echo of phpinfo();

Comment: I do have 2 php.ini, but what to change in them?